# How can I make different service names for ruby opentelemetry instrumentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-telemetry

I set up opentelemetry for my rails app, but I need different service names per instrument.

Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
#config/initializers/opentelemetry.rb
OpenTelemetry::SDK.configure do |c|
  c.service_name = 'HttpClient'
  c.use('OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::HttpClient')
end

OpenTelemetry::SDK.configure do |c|
  c.service_name = 'Net'
  c.use('OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::Net')
end

OpenTelemetry::SDK.configure do |c|
  c.service_name = 'PG'
  c.use('OpenTelemetry::Instrumentation::PG')
end
#... and so on
```

But I think this is not the right way of achieving what I want.
Is there a better way?